# Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-api, mean-stack

I am currently implementing a Google login and Google calendar implementation and testing out a function when a Google user logs in it pulls their events and prints to the console. however, I am getting the following error in the console

> Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

and when I console.log the calendar, it gives me a null.

I have made sure Google+ API and Google calendar API are both enabled in the console as well.

I am new to web development in general, I followed a tutorial to get me started and began trying to use the Google API's. I am using the MEAN stack for this project. Here is the relevant code.

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');
var session = require('express-session');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = 'check123';
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var gcal = require('google-calendar');
var google = require('googleapis');


module.exports = function(app,passport, auth) {


    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: false }
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username, email: user.email }, secret, {expiresIn: '24h'});
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
            clientID: '422080801499546',
            clientSecret: '34f91021248106dea49daa111bb7ff89',
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback",
            profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log(profile._json.email);
            User.findOne({ email: profile._json.email }).select('username password email').exec(function(err, user){
                if(err) done(err);

                if (user && user !== null) {
                    done(null, user);
                } else {
                    done(err);
                }
            });
            //done(null, profile);
        }
    ));



// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in Passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, an accessToken, refreshToken, and Google
//   profile), and invoke a callback with a user object.
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: '655984940226-ob15jvq3hvqha4969tlb3oco9tun1i9t.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            clientSecret: 'hsZtBDsfiCvdPz0gT-tqdUZ_',
            callbackURL: "https://frozen-woodland-75947.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback"
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            User.findOne({ email: profile.emails[0].value }).select('username password email').exec(function(err, user){
                if(err) done(err);

                if (user && user !== null) {
                    done(null, user);
                } else {
                    done(err);
                }
            });

            var google_calendar = google.calendar('v3');
            console.log('im here');
            google_calendar.events.list({
                auth: auth,
                calendarId: 'primary',
                timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
                singleEvents: true,
                orderBy: 'startTime'
            }, function(err, calendarList){
                console.log(calendarList);
                if(err){
                    console.log('bad list: ' + err);
                    return;
                }
                var events = calendarList.items;
                if(events.length ==0){
                    console.log('No items found');
                } else {
                    console.log('Upcoming events:');
                    console.log('%s -%s', start, event.summary);
                }

            })
        }
```

Next is my authentication functions, my api.js:

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = 'check123';

module.exports = function(router){

    //USER REGISTRATION
    router.post('/users', function(req, res){
        var user = new User();
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.email = req.body.email;
        if(req.body.username == null || req.body.username == ''|| req.body.password == null || req.body.email == null || req.body.password == '' || req.body.email == ''){
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Ensure username, email, and password were provided'}); //false if the route is null empty etc.
        } else {
            user.save(function(err){
            if(err) {
                res.json({success: false, message: 'Username or email already exists'});
            } else {
                res.json({success: true, message: 'user created!'});
            }
        });

        }
    });

    //USER LOGIN ROUTE
    //http://localhost:port/api/authenticate
    router.post('/authenticate', function(req,res){
        User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).select('email username password').exec(function(err,user){
            if(err) throw err;

            if(!user){
                res.json({success: false, message: 'Could not authenticate user'});
            } else if (user) {
                if( req.body.password) {
                    var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
                } else {
                    res.json({success: false, message: 'No password Provided'});
                }
                if(!validPassword) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: ' Could not Authenticate password'});
                } else {
                    var token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username, email: user.email }, secret, {expiresIn: '24h'}); // create json token when they successfully log in with secret encryption and expires in 24 hours
                    res.json({ success: true, message: ' User Authenticated!', token: token}); // respond to user with that token
                }
            }
        });
    });

    router.use(function(req, res, next){
        var token = req.body.token || req.body.query || req.headers['x-access-token'];
        console.log(token);
        if(token) {
            //varify token
            jwt.verify(token,secret,function(err,decoded){
                if(err) {
                    res.json({success: false, message: 'Token invalid'});

                } else {
                    req.decoded = decoded; //decrpyts token - user/email
                    next();
                }
            });
        }else {
            res.json({success: false, message: 'No token provided'});
        }
    });

    router.post('/me', function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.decoded);
    });

    return router;
}
```

Login controllers:

```
    //controls main index - runs when main page loads

angular.module('mainController', ['authServices'])


    .controller('mainCtrl', function(Auth,$timeout, $location,$rootScope, $window){
        var app = this; // so we can access outside of scoper

        app.loadme = false;

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
            if(Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                app.isLoggedIn = true;
                Auth.getUser().then(function(data){
                    app.username = data.data.username;
                    app.useremail = data.data.email;
                    app.loadme = true;
                });
            } else {
                app.isLoggedIn = false;
                app.username = '';
                app.loadme = true;

            }
        });

        this.google = function() {
            $window.location = $window.location.protocol + '//' + $window.location.host + '/auth/google';
        };



        this.doLogin = function(loginData) { //when the register button is pressed controller
            app.loading = true;
            app.errorMsg = false;

            Auth.login(app.loginData).then(function(data){
                if(data.data.success){
                    app.loading = false;
                    app.successMsg = data.data.message + '...redirecting';
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $location.path('/about');
                        app.loginData = '';
                        app.successMsg = false;
                    }, 2000);



                } else {
                    app.loading = false;
                    app.errorMsg = data.data.message;


                }
            });
        };
        this.logout = function() {
            Auth.logout();
            $location.path('/logout');
            $timeout(function(){
                $location.path('/');
            }, 2000);
        };
    })
```

Comment: The problem is that you are not properly applying your authentication to the requests to Google.   Which request is giving the error?

Comment: @DaImTo   
I am getting the error after implementing the second part of the googlestrategy, where I try to access the events on the calendar to print to the console